# How to use the "require" keyword in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

What is the equivalent of the line `const stripe = require('stripe')('some_key');` in NextJS?

I'm too familiar with the `require` keyword with NextJS.

```js
const stripe = require('stripe')('some_key');

app.post('/create-customer-portal-session', async (req, res) => {
  // Authenticate your user.
  const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
    customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
    return_url: 'https://example.com/account',
  });

  res.redirect(session.url);
});
```

I tried using `dynamic` but I don't think I'm using it right since the compiler throws an error.

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DynamicComp = dynamic() => import(('stripe')('some_key'));
...
```

From https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const DynamicComp = dynamic(() => import(('stripe')('some_key')));
```